# Is there a way to refactor this javascript into two event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

```
$('.main').on('mouseleave', '.left_inner_element', function(event){
  $('.left_inner_element').removeClass('inner_hover');
});

$('.main').on('mouseover', '.right_element', function(event){
  $('.right_element').addClass('outer_hover');
});

$('.main').on('mouseleave', '.right_element', function(event){
  $('.right_element').removeClass('outer_hover');
});

$('.main').on('mouseover', '.right_inner_element', function(event){
  $('.right_inner_element').addClass('inner_hover');
});

$('.main').on('mouseleave', '.right_inner_element', function(event){
  $('.right_inner_element').removeClass('inner_hover');
});

$('.main').on('mouseover', '.bottom_element', function(event){
  $('.bottom_element').addClass('outer_hover');
});

$('.main').on('mouseleave', '.bottom_element', function(event){
  $('.bottom_element').removeClass('outer_hover');
});
```

As you can see they are all the same other then the class the event handler is on and the inner or outer_hover...

Comment: Why not just combine all the lines of code from "mouseleave" handlers into a single one, and the same for "mouseover"?

Comment: Each class has a mouseleave and a mouseover event which sets a class which causes a hover on multiple elements....@Pointy - how can I do that

Comment: Why is there `outer_hover` and `inner_hover` classes? Can you change to a single class `hover` and apply different styles as in `.bottom_element.hover{}` `.right_inner_element.hover{}`, and so on?

Comment: @Trace - did my solution work for you? If not, please tell me and I'll get it fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$('.main').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.left_inner_element, .right_inner_element', function(e){    
    var selector = $(this).hasClass('.left_inner_element') ? '.left_inner_element' : '.right_inner_element';
    $(selector).toggleClass('inner_hover');
});

$('.main').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.right_element, .bottom_element', function(e){
    var selector = $(this).hasClass('.right_element') ? '.right_element' : '.bottom_element';
    $(selector).toggleClass('outer_hover');
});
```

My original code only added the class to the hovered instance of the element, this version adds the class to **all** instances of the hovered class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the same thing to happen to each element (I'm imagining a sort of highlighting type of deal), so I would add another class in all your elements lets call it `.foo` Then I'd add the hover event for that class.

```
$('.foo').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('outer_hover')
    $(this).toggleClass('inner_hover')
}, function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('outer_hover')
    $(this).toggleClass('inner_hover')
});
```